# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-modeldownloader

Tags: android, firebase, machine-learning, deployment

I get following error while Sync my project :

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-modeldownloader:

I followed the steps mentioned on the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/android/use-custom-models?authuser=0), in the section Use a custom TensorFlow Lite model on Android

What are my options to resolve this error?

> My Gradle:

```
//firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    //use multi firebase service
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    //firebase-auth
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.3'
    //firebase-fireStore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2'
    //firebase-realTime database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
    //firebase-storage database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.2'

    // Declare the dependency for the Firebase ML model downloader library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-modeldownloader'

    // Also declare the dependency for the TensorFlow Lite library and specify its version
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.3.0'
```

Comment: I was not able to replicate the issue, can you share your app & module `build.gradle` ?

Comment: I updated the post, please check it again ,@TiagoOliveira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that my dependency:`implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')` is not updated it was (`26.4.0`).

So the answer is to update Bom-dependency to: `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')`